# Should I write toJson or fromJson method in Kotlin data class?

Tags: kotlin, coding-style, clean-architecture

It's mentioned that a Kotlin data class is for storing data. It's equivalent to the data structure. As such, it shouldn't have any behaviour method. In clean code, implementing behaviour method in a data class would violate many principles namely, SRP, OCP, ...

I was wondering if the `fromJson` and `toJson` methods are considered as behaviour method. If it is, then where should I implement those methods in my code?

I'm using Kotlin data class to store User, Product, etc. In my supposedly clean architecture and clean code that I am learning, I restricted those data class to a corner for storing only domain data.

I tried to find information about this but I can't seem to find anyone talking about data class and these methods.

Here's the code I've imagined. It should be something like this.

```
data class User(val id: String, val name: String) {
    fun toJson(): Json {}
    fun fromJson(json: Json): User {}
}
```

Or should I have other class responsible for toJson and fromJson implementation?

Comment: there're some functions in itself, such as `hashCode()`, `toString()`, `copy()`.

reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html

Comment: I think that's different from what I'm about to do. Those function won't change so It won't affect the clean code or clean architecture.

Comment: not sure how "clean" is

Comment: Just use a library like [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization). Do not create `toJson` or `fromJson` methods in the data classes. If you are writing a small application which needs to transform objects to json sometimes, this should be enough. If you are writing a web application, then there should be support for json serialization in your framework and all serialization shall be done by the framework.

Comment: FYI, [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) is a better [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and recommended by Gson authors if you want to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged your query with clean architecture I assume you refer to https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html.

From this perspective a "domain entity" should be independent from any kind of serialization format, persistence aspects or other specific "technology" or "framework".

A common pattern to handle "persistence ignorance" for domain objects is the repository pattern. An important aspect here to keep in mind in context of clean architecture is that the interface of the repository is defined in the "use case layer" (business logic) while the implementation is in the "gateway layer" or even "framework layer".